# connecting to neo4j via py2neo on digitalocean error

Tags: neo4j, digital-ocean, py2neo

I have a droplet on digital ocean and have neo4j installed and running, the results of `service neo4j status` is:

```
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/neo4j; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (exited) since Wed 2017-04-19 10:35:43 UTC; 21h ago
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
 Process: 725 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/neo4j stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Process: 806 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/neo4j start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Tasks: 0
 Memory: 0B
 CPU: 0
```

But when I run the pyhthon code I get:

```
py2neo.packages.httpstream.http.SocketError: Connection refused
```

I have authentication disabled.

In the graph all I explicitly referred to the db:

```
G=Graph('http://localhost:7474/db/data')
```

which results in the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/py2neo/packages/neo4j/v1/bolt.py", line 156, in _recv
raise ProtocolError("Server closed connection")
py2neo.packages.neo4j.v1.exceptions.ProtocolError: Server closed connection
```

Comment: What does `curl http://localhost:7474/db/data` say?

Comment: curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 7474: Connection refused

Comment: So apparantly neo4j is not accesible. Not a problem with py2neo. Check and post your config in a new question.